# taking just two digits of a Number of type double without rounding it

Tags: c#

I have this Number

```
double Nb=4.9584763251
```

how can I make get only two digits after the comma without rounding the number :

```
Nb=`4.95` and not `4.96`
```

using the `Math.Round(Nb,2)` will return `4.96`
is there any way to fix this ?

Comment: Do you want to keep it as a number or just display as text?

Comment: keep it as a number because later i want to compare it with other variable

Comment: Use `decimal` instead of `float` otherwise any operation on it can introduce rounding errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use `Math.Truncate(Nb * 100) / 100m`

Comment: As the answers to the duplicate question show, float should be avoided otherwise rounding errors are unavoidable

Comment: Changed, thanks for the hint

Answer (score 0):

```
 double x = ((int)(Nb*100))/100.0
```

Comment: this would give me `4.0`

Comment: I'd use `decimal x`, i.e. `decimal x = ((int)(Nb * 100)) / 100m;`

Comment: @Sora You might have set the braces whrong